# How to run MP3 and other media files?

Tags: mp3

I am new to Ubuntu. After installation I am unable to play the media files like MP4, MP4 etc. What to do??
Thanks in Advance

Comment: you also want to install `ubuntu-restricted-extra` from software center then try running media files

Answer (score 1):

It is realy simple..

**Install ubuntu-restricted-extras.**
For, that in your terminal enter.

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

It will ask for your root password.(For getting terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.)

For assistance feel free to visit [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats).

And also please do some search before asking questions.